# How to keep Unity Launcher hidden and locked but Super key should launch the Dash?

Tags: unity, launcher, unity-dash

I'd like to keep the Unity Launcher *hidden* and *locked* to that state. But the <kbd>Super</kbd> key should still be able to launch the Dash. (With the auto-hide launcher feature enabled, tapping Super key for Dash doesn't seem to work when there's no active windows i.e. when desktop is shown. Is there any solution to that?) Also, the launcher should not appear when I launch the *Dash* or the *panel run dialogue*. I'd like to know if there is there a hack to launch Dash with mouse gesture.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So basically all you want to do is to keep Unity Launcher hidden and locked but Super key should launch the Dash. I guess we have to tweak our way around it. Try the below mentioned and let me know how it worked out for you. Basically you have to first install CCSM for this. After installing, run the application and go to `Unity Section` and then to `Experimental` Tab.  Set the following values as mentioned :
a) Launcher Opacity 0.000
b) Reveal Edge 0.200
c) Reveal Pressure 999
d) Edge Overcome Pressure 1
e) Mouse Pressure Decay 1
f) Edge Stop 1
g) Menu Fade In 1 and rest all 0
h) Launcher  Captures Mouse `unchecked`.

hope it helps.

Comment: manipulation of threshold for the _edge-press launcher release_ works... but still no success with _... launcher should not appear when I launch the Dash..._ part (... and the last one too). +1 for the help, thank you... any ideas with the rest?...

Comment: @ajThapa I guess you can tweak around the settings. Let me see what I can do & will get back.